# Magento 2.1.2 Issue with getting current website

Tags: magento2, websites, multi-website

`$currentWebsite = $block->getCurrentWebsite();` is returning `NULL` even when the website has been well configured.

Where should I check in the databases or at the backend, in order to solve for this issue?

Comment: add your block class

Answer (score 1):

### Options : 1 (Using Object Manager)

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$store = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$storeId = $store->getStore()->getId();
$currentStoreID = $store->getStore($storeId)->getWebsiteId(); //Website ID
$currentStoreName = $store->getStore($storeId)->getWebsiteName(); //Website Name
```

### Options : 2 (Using construct)

```
protected $storeManager;

public function __construct(
    .....
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    .....
){
    .....
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    .....
}

public function getCurrentWebsiteId()
{
    $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    $currentStoreID = $this->storeManager->getStore($storeId)->getWebsiteId();
    $currentStoreName = $this->storeManager->getStore($storeId)->getWebsiteName();
    echo $currentStoreName; // Current Website Name
    return $currentStoreID;
}
```

You can add Options : 2 code in your block and access in phtml like `echo $block->getCurrentWebsiteId();`

I hope it will helpful for you.

Comment: This shows the Website ID, but I'd like to have the current website

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Comment: @JulianMurillo is it working for you?

Comment: I get the website ID anyway; for Instance I expect 'Spain' -which is the current website- instead of '5' which is the website ID

Comment: Check my updated answer. You can now accept and upvote answer if it's helpful for you. So, other user will use this answer in their logic. :)